# characteristic function of random variable, find distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $f_{X}(t)$ - characteristic function of random variable $X$ and $f\equiv 1$ when $t \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, where $\epsilon>0$ what we can say about random variable $X$?
I know the property of characterisitc function: If there is exist an absoutle moment of order k $(E|X|^k<\infty$) of random variable $X$ then $f^{(k)}(0) = i^kEX^k$. Can i use that in case of this exersice?
I mean $f^{(2)}(0) =0 =-EX^2 \Rightarrow X$ has degenerate distribution and $X\equiv const$? Can i argue that the second moment exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has finite moment of order $k$ then $f$ is $k-$ times  differentiable. Converse is true for even values of $k$. Here we have $k=2$ so it is correct to say that $EX^{2}=0$ and hence $X=0$ almost surely.

Comment: To justify differentiability under the integral, it is necessary to use the Lebesgue theorem, but we don't know anything about $EX^2$? Could you give me a hint how to proof this statement?

Comment: This is fairly standard. See Theorem 6.4.1 (page 166) in K L Chung's 'A Course in Probability Theory'. @Sneachhcaens

Comment: Thank you, friend